# Ionic Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

I am developing ionic app and facing error when executing `ionic cordova build android` in command prompt I get following error.

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\Sushant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME="C:\Users\Sushant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk" (DEPRECATED) Using Android SDK: C:\Users\Sushant\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

> BUILD FAILED in 8s Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Sushant\NewApp\branches\MobileApp\App\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Sushant\NewApp\branches\MobileApp\App\platforms\android\build.gradle

I have tried removing android pplatform and adding again, still facing same error. I'm not sure what is going wrong with the configuration. I have tried to update target sdk or min sdk version as well, still facing same error shown.

My build.gradle code is as below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

buildscript {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    if(cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
        String defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion = kotlin_version

        /**
         * Fetches the user's defined Kotlin Version from config.xml.
         * If the version is not set or invalid, it will default to the ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}
         */
        String gradlePluginKotlinVersion = cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinVersion', defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion)
        if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(gradlePluginKotlinVersion)) {
            println("The defined Kotlin version (${gradlePluginKotlinVersion}) does not appear to be a valid version. Falling back to version: ${defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion}.")
            gradlePluginKotlinVersion = defaultGradlePluginKotlinVersion
        }

        // Change the version to be used.
        ext.kotlin_version = gradlePluginKotlinVersion
    }

    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos

    dependencies {
        apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'

        if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }

        if(cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
            String defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = '4.2.0'

            /**
             * Fetches the user's defined Google Services Plugin Version from config.xml.
             * If the version is not set or invalid, it will default to the ${defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}
             */
            String gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion', defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion)
            if(!cdvHelpers.isVersionValid(gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion)) {
                println("The defined Google Services plugin version (${gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}) does not appear to be a valid version. Falling back to version: ${defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}.")
                gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion = defaultGradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion
            }

            // Create the Google Services classpath and set it.
            String gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath = "com.google.gms:google-services:${gradlePluginGoogleServicesVersion}"
            println "Adding classpath: ${gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath}"
            classpath gradlePluginGoogleServicesClassPath
        }
    }
}

// Allow plugins to declare Maven dependencies via build-extras.gradle.
allprojects {
    apply from: 'repositories.gradle'
    repositories repos
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '6.5'
}

// Configuration properties. Set these via environment variables, build-extras.gradle, or gradle.properties.
// Refer to: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_this_and_that.html
ext {
    apply from: '../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'

    // The value for android.compileSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvCompileSdkVersion')) {
        cdvCompileSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // The value for android.buildToolsVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildToolsVersion')) {
        cdvBuildToolsVersion = null;
    }
    // Sets the versionCode to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCode')) {
        cdvVersionCode = null
    }
    // Sets the minSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMinSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMinSdkVersion = null
    }
    // Sets the maxSdkVersion to the given value.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvMaxSdkVersion')) {
        cdvMaxSdkVersion = null
    }
    // The value for android.targetSdkVersion.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvTargetSdkVersion')) {
        cdvTargetSdkVersion = null;
    }
    // Whether to build architecture-specific APKs.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildMultipleApks')) {
        cdvBuildMultipleApks = null
    }
    // Whether to append a 0 "abi digit" to versionCode when only a single APK is build
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit')) {
        cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for release signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // .properties files to use for debug signing.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile')) {
        cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = null
    }
    // Set by build.js script.
    if (!project.hasProperty('cdvBuildArch')) {
        cdvBuildArch = null
    }

    // Plugin gradle extensions can append to this to have code run at the end.
    cdvPluginPostBuildExtras = []
}

// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS START
// PLUGIN GRADLE EXTENSIONS END

def hasBuildExtras1 = file('build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras1) {
    apply from: 'build-extras.gradle'
}

def hasBuildExtras2 = file('../build-extras.gradle').exists()
if (hasBuildExtras2) {
    apply from: '../build-extras.gradle'
}

// Set property defaults after extension .gradle files.
ext.cdvCompileSdkVersion = cdvCompileSdkVersion == null ? (
    defaultCompileSdkVersion == null
        ? privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
        : defaultCompileSdkVersion
) : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvCompileSdkVersion);

if (ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion == null) {
    ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
    //ext.cdvBuildToolsVersion = project.ext.defaultBuildToolsVersion
}
if (ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../debug-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile = '../debug-signing.properties'
}
if (ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile == null && file('../release-signing.properties').exists()) {
    ext.cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile = '../release-signing.properties'
}

// Cast to appropriate types.
ext.cdvBuildMultipleApks = cdvBuildMultipleApks == null ? false : cdvBuildMultipleApks.toBoolean();
ext.cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit = cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit == null ? false : cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit.toBoolean();

// minSdkVersion, maxSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
ext.cdvMinSdkVersion = cdvMinSdkVersion == null ? defaultMinSdkVersion : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
    ext.cdvMaxSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt('' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
}
ext.cdvTargetSdkVersion = cdvTargetSdkVersion == null ? defaultTargetSdkVersion  : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)

ext.cdvVersionCode = cdvVersionCode == null ? null : Integer.parseInt('' + cdvVersionCode)

def computeBuildTargetName(debugBuild) {
    def ret = 'assemble'
    if (cdvBuildMultipleApks && cdvBuildArch) {
        def arch = cdvBuildArch == 'arm' ? 'armv7' : cdvBuildArch
        ret += '' + arch.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + arch.substring(1);
    }
    return ret + (debugBuild ? 'Debug' : 'Release')
}

// Make cdvBuild a task that depends on the debug/arch-sepecific task.
task cdvBuildDebug
cdvBuildDebug.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(true)
}

task cdvBuildRelease
cdvBuildRelease.dependsOn {
    return computeBuildTargetName(false)
}

task cdvPrintProps {
    doLast {
        println('cdvCompileSdkVersion=' + cdvCompileSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildToolsVersion=' + cdvBuildToolsVersion)
        println('cdvVersionCode=' + cdvVersionCode)
        println('cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit=' + cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)
        println('cdvMinSdkVersion=' + cdvMinSdkVersion)
        println('cdvMaxSdkVersion=' + cdvMaxSdkVersion)
        println('cdvTargetSdkVersion=' + cdvTargetSdkVersion)
        println('cdvBuildMultipleApks=' + cdvBuildMultipleApks)
        println('cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile=' + cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile)
        println('cdvBuildArch=' + cdvBuildArch)
        println('computedVersionCode=' + android.defaultConfig.versionCode)
        android.productFlavors.each { flavor ->
            println('computed' + flavor.name.capitalize() + 'VersionCode=' + flavor.versionCode)
        }
    }
}

android {
    defaultConfig {
        versionCode cdvVersionCode ?: new BigInteger("" + privateHelpers.extractIntFromManifest("versionCode"))
        applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")

        if (cdvMinSdkVersion != null) {
            minSdkVersion cdvMinSdkVersion
        }

        if (cdvMaxSdkVersion != null) {
            maxSdkVersion cdvMaxSdkVersion
        }

        if(cdvTargetSdkVersion != null) {
            targetSdkVersion cdvTargetSdkVersion
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
      abortOnError false;
    }

    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion

    // This code exists for Crosswalk and other Native APIs.
    // By default, we multiply the existing version code in the
    // Android Manifest by 10 and add a number for each architecture.
    // If you are not using Crosswalk or SQLite, you can
    // ignore this chunk of code, and your version codes will be respected.

    if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvBuildMultipleApks)) {
        flavorDimensions "default"

        productFlavors {
            armeabi {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 1
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi"]
                }
            }
            armv7 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 2
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["armeabi-v7a"]
                }
            }
            arm64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 3
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["arm64-v8a"]
                }
            }
            x86 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 4
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86"]
                }
            }
            x86_64 {
                versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10 + 5
                ndk {
                    abiFilters = ["x86_64"]
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (Boolean.valueOf(cdvVersionCodeForceAbiDigit)) {
        // This provides compatibility to the default logic for versionCode before cordova-android 5.2.0
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode defaultConfig.versionCode*10
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    if (cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                // These must be set or Gradle will complain (even if they are overridden).
                keyAlias = ""
                keyPassword = "__unset" // And these must be set to non-empty in order to have the signing step added to the task graph.
                storeFile = null
                storePassword = "__unset"
            }
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
        addSigningProps(cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.release)
    }

    if (cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile) {
        addSigningProps(cdvDebugSigningPropertiesFile, signingConfigs.debug)
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
}

/*
 * WARNING: Cordova Lib and platform scripts do management inside of this code here,
 * if you are adding the dependencies manually, do so outside the comments, otherwise
 * the Cordova tools will overwrite them
 */


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginKotlinEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    }

    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    implementation(project(path: ":CordovaLib"))
    implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.1"
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES END
}

def promptForReleaseKeyPassword() {
    if (!cdvReleaseSigningPropertiesFile) {
        return;
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key store password: ')
    }
    if ('__unset'.equals(android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword)) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = privateHelpers.promptForPassword('Enter key password: ');
    }
}

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    taskGraph.getAllTasks().each() { task ->
      if(['validateReleaseSigning', 'validateSigningRelease', 'validateSigningArmv7Release', 'validateSigningX76Release'].contains(task.name)) {
         promptForReleaseKeyPassword()
      }
    }
}

def addSigningProps(propsFilePath, signingConfig) {
    def propsFile = file(propsFilePath)
    def props = new Properties()
    propsFile.withReader { reader ->
        props.load(reader)
    }

    def storeFile = new File(props.get('key.store') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'storeFile'))
    if (!storeFile.isAbsolute()) {
        storeFile = RelativePath.parse(true, storeFile.toString()).getFile(propsFile.getParentFile())
    }
    if (!storeFile.exists()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException('Keystore file does not exist: ' + storeFile.getAbsolutePath())
    }
    signingConfig.keyAlias = props.get('key.alias') ?: privateHelpers.ensureValueExists(propsFilePath, props, 'keyAlias')
    signingConfig.keyPassword = props.get('keyPassword', props.get('key.alias.password', signingConfig.keyPassword))
    signingConfig.storeFile = storeFile
    signingConfig.storePassword = props.get('storePassword', props.get('key.store.password', signingConfig.storePassword))
    def storeType = props.get('storeType', props.get('key.store.type', ''))
    if (!storeType) {
        def filename = storeFile.getName().toLowerCase();
        if (filename.endsWith('.p12') || filename.endsWith('.pfx')) {
            storeType = 'pkcs12'
        } else {
            storeType = signingConfig.storeType // "jks"
        }
    }
    signingConfig.storeType = storeType
}

for (def func : cdvPluginPostBuildExtras) {
    func()
}

// This can be defined within build-extras.gradle as:
//     ext.postBuildExtras = { ... code here ... }
if (hasProperty('postBuildExtras')) {
    postBuildExtras()
}

if (cdvHelpers.getConfigPreference('GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled', 'false').toBoolean()) {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

`ionic info` is shown as below:
Ionic:

- Ionic CLI                     : 6.13.1
  (C:\Users\Sushant\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@ionic\cli)
  Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.13
  @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.803.29
  @angular-devkit/schematics    : 8.1.3    @angular/cli
  : 8.1.3    @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.0.0

Cordova:

- Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0    Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
  Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0,
  cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 14 other plugins)

Utility:

- cordova-res : 0.15.3
  native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

- NodeJS : v12.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
  npm    : not
  installed    OS     : Windows 10

Please let me know if any more information needed to elaborate the issue.